# Unable to copy MariaDB data dir in a multi stage Docker build

Tags: linux, docker, mariadb

I'am trying to create a new Docker image from `mariadb:10.3.12` that holds a predefined database schema `collectives` and some pre filled database tables within that schema.

My `Dockerfile` does declares two stages:

1. The first stage is the builder stage and responsible for creating the schema `collectives` and import data into that schema.
2. The second stage should then simply copy the data dir of the first stage. It therefore is a preinitialized MariaDB Docker image.

And this is how the `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM mariadb:10.3.12 as builder

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=collectives
ENV MYSQL_USER=abc
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=abc

ADD server.jar app.jar
ADD openjdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /usr/lib/jvm
ADD import.sh import.sh

RUN chmod +x import.sh && ./import.sh

FROM mariadb:10.3.12

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=collectives
ENV MYSQL_USER=abc
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=abc

COPY --from=builder /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql

EXPOSE 3306

ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh", "mysqld",  "--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci", "--character-set-server=utf8mb4",  "--innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0"]
```

When I build the `Dockerfile` using

```
docker build -t huhu .
```

everything in the first `builder` stage works as expected. Means the MariaDB starts. It then creates the schema `collectives`. The data gets imported by the `import.sh` script.

Within the `import.sh` I have added the debug command `tree /var/lib/mysql` that lists the content of `/var/lib/mysql` to the console. The result of the command is:

```
/var/lib/mysql
|-- aria_log.00000001
|-- aria_log_control
|-- collectives
|   |-- collective_partner.frm
|   |-- collective_partner.ibd
|   |-- db.opt
|   |-- flyway_schema_history.frm
|   |-- flyway_schema_history.ibd
|   |-- price_record.frm
|   `-- price_record.ibd
|-- ib_buffer_pool
|-- ib_logfile0
|-- ib_logfile1
|-- ibdata1
|-- multi-master.info
|-- mysql
|   |-- column_stats.MYD
|   |-- column_stats.MYI
|   |-- column_stats.frm
|   |-- columns_priv.MYD
|   |-- columns_priv.MYI
|   |-- columns_priv.frm
|   |-- db.MYD
|   |-- db.MYI
|   |-- db.frm
|   |-- event.MYD
|   |-- event.MYI
|   |-- event.frm
|   |-- func.MYD
|   |-- func.MYI
|   |-- func.frm
|   |-- general_log.CSM
|   |-- general_log.CSV
|   |-- general_log.frm
|   |-- gtid_slave_pos.frm
|   |-- gtid_slave_pos.ibd
|   |-- help_category.MYD
|   |-- help_category.MYI
|   |-- help_category.frm
|   |-- help_keyword.MYD
|   |-- help_keyword.MYI
|   |-- help_keyword.frm
|   |-- help_relation.MYD
|   |-- help_relation.MYI
|   |-- help_relation.frm
|   |-- help_topic.MYD
|   |-- help_topic.MYI
|   |-- help_topic.frm
|   |-- host.MYD
|   |-- host.MYI
|   |-- host.frm
|   |-- index_stats.MYD
|   |-- index_stats.MYI
|   |-- index_stats.frm
|   |-- innodb_index_stats.frm
|   |-- innodb_index_stats.ibd
|   |-- innodb_table_stats.frm
|   |-- innodb_table_stats.ibd
|   |-- plugin.MYD
|   |-- plugin.MYI
|   |-- plugin.frm
|   |-- proc.MYD
|   |-- proc.MYI
|   |-- proc.frm
|   |-- procs_priv.MYD
|   |-- procs_priv.MYI
|   |-- procs_priv.frm
|   |-- proxies_priv.MYD
|   |-- proxies_priv.MYI
|   |-- proxies_priv.frm
|   |-- roles_mapping.MYD
|   |-- roles_mapping.MYI
|   |-- roles_mapping.frm
|   |-- servers.MYD
|   |-- servers.MYI
|   |-- servers.frm
|   |-- slow_log.CSM
|   |-- slow_log.CSV
|   |-- slow_log.frm
|   |-- table_stats.MYD
|   |-- table_stats.MYI
|   |-- table_stats.frm
|   |-- tables_priv.MYD
|   |-- tables_priv.MYI
|   |-- tables_priv.frm
|   |-- time_zone.MYD
|   |-- time_zone.MYI
|   |-- time_zone.frm
|   |-- time_zone_leap_second.MYD
|   |-- time_zone_leap_second.MYI
|   |-- time_zone_leap_second.frm
|   |-- time_zone_name.MYD
|   |-- time_zone_name.MYI
|   |-- time_zone_name.frm
|   |-- time_zone_transition.MYD
|   |-- time_zone_transition.MYI
|   |-- time_zone_transition.frm
|   |-- time_zone_transition_type.MYD
|   |-- time_zone_transition_type.MYI
|   |-- time_zone_transition_type.frm
|   |-- transaction_registry.frm
|   |-- transaction_registry.ibd
|   |-- user.MYD
|   |-- user.MYI
|   `-- user.frm
`-- performance_schema
    `-- db.opt
```

So as you can see in the first stage everything is there. But it seems that `COPY --from=builder /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql` in the second stage does not find the same data in that directory.

I was inspecting the result Docker image using [Dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) and the `COPY` instruction seems to result in a no operation step.

[image: Inspection result]

Can anyone tell me why Docker does not copy these files to the 2nd stage? Any hints are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `/var/lib/mysql` is a volume in mariadb image, so that can be a problem. Try 'mkdir /data && sed -i -e "s#/var/lib/mysql#/data#g" /etc/mysql/my.cnf && grep datadir /etc/mysql/my.cnf' before importing and copy data from `/data`.

Comment: @JanGaraj this is in fact true. Thank you for pointing me the right direction. If you add this as an answer I will accept it. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/lib/mysql` is a volume in mariadb image, so data are not stored in the image. Store data in the image, not in default volume. For example run:

```
mkdir /data && sed -i -e "s#/var/lib/mysql#/data#g" /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

before import and copy data from `/data`.